# InstaFeed.js: Change thumb size from 150x150 to 250x250

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im using the Instafeed script to get the instagram feed and display it on my page. See [GitHub](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js). You can see it working live on [my page](https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/index.html) (bottom side)

It's work's, the only problem is that the script get the 150x150 thumb resolution, and I want the 250x250px because I want to make the custom height to 210px (Using the max-height and width auto on the CSS img class).

```
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '5388417298',
        accessToken: '5388417298.1677ed0.e3460b92c6f445c98d18f18635f740cf',
          resolution: 'standard_resolution',
  template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
  sortBy: 'most-recent',
  limit: 6,
  resolution: 'thumbnail',
  orientation: 'square',

    });
    userFeed.run();
```

CSS

```
#instafeed a img {
  max-height: 210px;
width: auto;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution options with Instafeed are `thumbnail`, `low_resolution` and `standard_resolution`. These translate to the image sizes provided by the Instragram API. These are a 150px x 150px thumbnail, an image with a max size of 320px and an image with a max size of 640px.

So to display at 210px x 210px I would go for the middle one (`low_resolution`). Change this line:

```
resolution: 'thumbnail',
```

to

```
resolution: 'low_resolution',
```

This won't provide a cropped square however, I would suggest you handle this in your CSS. One way would be to use `object-fit: cover` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and make sure the `img` is square. For example you could do the following:

```
#instafeed a img {
   height: 210px;
   width: 210px;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

Check the browser support for 'object-fit' to make sure it is suitable for your project

Comment: This fix don't display the square size, some images are landscape. I want to display the square size. You can check it in the live page: https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/index.html

Comment: For anything larger than 150px the Instagram API gives you the image just scaled down rather than cropped, so if it is not square on Instagram it won't be square when you get it. I have edited my answer to make this clearer and suggest an approach

Comment: See the example in the bottom of here, look the CSS: https://esperantojewelry.com/ If you go to the image url of any item Apparently it shows a background image non-squared but they cropped it to make a 210x210px square, how I can do it?

Comment: The way I have specified above will do that. As will the technique they have used on that page, setting it as a `background-image` with a size of `cover`. I think my method above is probably better as the image remains in the markup

Comment: Check it now: https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/index.html Now it is squared but I think he is using the 150x150px image scaled instead the 320px image...

Comment: The script is failing to load on that page for me